# Equivalent Spring @Controller with @RequestMapping("/endpoint"), but using Java EE 8 only

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

So I'm working on implementing Oath2 authentication to allow my app to access Intuit Quickbooks company resources (items, customers, etc).

Intuit provides working examples using Spring, but I'm developing my app using JavaEE 8 with GlassFish5.

The Spring sample app callback contoller is structured as follows:

```
@Controller
public class CallbackController {
...
@RequestMapping("/oauth2redirect") 
public String callBackFromOAuth(@RequestParam("code") String authCode, @RequestParam("state") String state, @RequestParam(value = "realmId", required = false) String realmId, HttpSession session) {
...
 //after successful validation
 return "connected";
```

This is the redirect handler controller; which address it's configured at the intuit portal (in this case, http://localhost:8080/oauth2redirect) that will be called after user approves the app and intuit will send back authorization code  to this url.

So I'm a bit stuck finding what's the equivalent Spring callback redirect handler in JavaEE.

Is a @WebServlet or @WebService needed here? But then it wouldn't integrate nicely with JSF to just return the "connected" string so that it redirects to desired page (in this case connected.xhtml).

Not looking for workarounds, but the correct and standard way of implementing this on JavaEE. If you can point me to some sample apps out there or tutorials I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

*Here's full source code for [callback handler controller](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-JavaWithSDK/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/developer/sampleapp/oauth2/controller/CallbackController.java) and the [full sample app](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-JavaWithSDK).*

Comment: learn about jax-rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least not a really good alternative in JSF. Yes, you could 'abuse' JSF but there are other, better standards for this and this is (almost) what Spring also does. If you read the Spring Specs , you'll see the word 'Rest' being used a lot.

Well, there is a real java standard called 'Jax-RS' that is the standardized counterpart of what you do in spring.

[This](https://stormpath.com/blog/jax-rs-vs-spring-rest-endpoints) provides a decent analysis of the two So Jax-RS is the way to go.

But a `@WebServlet` or `@WebService` integrate perfectly with JSF. You can store any authentication information in the session and use that from JSF. No problem at all.

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, The article looks exactly what I was looking for. I'll take a look at it. Thanks for replying!

Comment: I tried hitting the UP button, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly display post score."

Comment: Ok... clear... no problem. Glad to help with further questions (jsf related ;-))